# Can't change volume or mute Sony headphones connected to Mac

Tags: mac, audio, headphones

I use some Sony headphones on an iMac and they've been working well for around 4 months.

Now, I start up my Mac to go to Safari and listen to some songs. I realize that my headphones are a bit loud. I hit F11 on my Apple keyboard to lower down the audio and for some reason it won't lower! I can hit the mute button and still nothing will happen.

Answer (score 2):

Try holding down the fn button, located at the bottom far left corner of the keyboard. Your keys might have somehow got switched up because I have found that if the buttons at the top do not work, holding fn and pressing the button makes it work

Comment: Kind of worked, but did not solve my problem.

Comment: @Gummy How has this not solved the problem completely? What more are you looking for to resolve the issue?